# Forming new 2d array by abstract some data in the other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, logic

In a scenario where I have a 2d array like this:

```
[
  [0,1,4,2,2,5,5,0],
  [1,1,4,4,2,2,5,3],
  [1,6,6,6,7,7,3,3],
]
```

And I wish to abstract the same number into a single new 2d array like the one below: {either one}

```
[
  [0,1],
  [1,1],
  [1,0]
]
```

---

```
[
  [2,2,0],
  [0,2,2]
]
```

---

```
[
  [0,3],
  [3,3]
]
```

---

```
[
  [4,0],
  [4,4]
]
```

---

```
[
  [5,5],
  [0,5]
]
```

---

```
[
  [6,6,6]
]
```

How can I make this kind of logic in javascript?
Basically, I need to have some sort of logic to generate **either one** multidimensional array on the above. Just imagine getting the same number from that 2d array.

Comment: Can you explain the rule of this transformation?

Comment: Why is there differents 6 answers  ? is it a random choice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @MisterJojo, yes [ [ 7, 7 ] ] will be one of them also. Sorry I missed one of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Initial Data
const arr = [
  [0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 0],
  [1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3],
  [1, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 3],
];

// Numbers you want to distribute to isolated arrays
const numbersForDistribute = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const result = [];

for (let n of numbersForDistribute) {

  // find range within initial array for each number 
  // to determine size of result array for it 
  let minRowIndex = 999;
  let maxRowIndex = 0;

  let minColumnIndex = 999;
  let maxColumnIndex = 0;

  for (let i in arr) {
    const row = arr[i];

    for (let j in row) {
      const currentElement = row[j];

      if (row[j] === n) {
        if (i < minRowIndex) {
          minRowIndex = i;
        }

        if (i > maxRowIndex) {
          maxRowIndex = i;
        }

        if (j < minColumnIndex) {
          minColumnIndex = j;
        }

        if (j > maxColumnIndex) {
          maxColumnIndex = j;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const resultForN = [];

  // build result array of specific size for each number 
  for (let i = minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex; i++) {
    resultForN.push([]);
    for (let j = minColumnIndex; j <= maxColumnIndex; j++) {
      resultForN[resultForN.length - 1].push(arr[i][j] === n ? n : 0);
    }
  }

  result.push(resultForN);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: @MisterJojo Hey chill, I can modify this into a 2d answer which I need, the main purpose here is to get the array which I need (I listed above). FocusRS show the way how to make it so this answer was acceptable. One more thing, thank you for your editing on the above answer so we can run the result on it.

Comment: Okay, so based on my case can you demonstrate to me what is the best way of asking a question in StackOverflow?

Comment: @KingsleyYong I will only do this if you explain why the answers =>`[[2,2,0],[0,2,2]]`versus`[[2,2],[2,2]]`and`[[5,5],[0,5]]`versus`[[0,5,5],[5,0,0]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245064/discussion-between-kingsley-yong-and-mister-jojo).